# can't access wp-admin giving me a white page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cloudflare, wp-admin, ss

I connected cloudflare to my WordPress and enabled HTTPS flexible.

made 2 page rules 
https://www.example.com/wp-login.php*
https://www.example.com/wp-admin/*
leaving SSL as flexible but disabling cache and security level

I did install two plugins
http-https-remover
https-redirection [which I disabled now]

I mistakenly changed my sit and home  urls to https://example.com
so I did access with FTP to fix it back , however the www is back still can't access the website
when I disable http-https-remover the website loads the content but its not aligned .

the website it self got the following errors :

www.site.com/:8 A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=f2befc48d1/cloudflare.min.js, is invoked via document.write. This MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.

but they are not effecting the look and feel of the website .

for https://www.example.com/wp-admin/ 
the console is empty and the page returnes 200

the http version(when I disabel ssl from cloudflare for the 2 page rules) it gives me.
"This page isn’t working

www.assesstm.com redirected you too many time"
console :GET http://www.assesstm.com/wp-admin/ net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
and the network is redirecting like crazy between http and https

disabling https in all the website gives me the redirect loop in the rest of the site

also worth mentioning that I'm not able to get the debug file after defining DEBUG with true in the wp-config.php file .
tried to force ssl on admin but didn't get a solution .

those are my wordpress plugins currently

```
a:14:{i:0;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";i:1;s:44:"css3-text-and-image-overlay/css3_overlay.php";i:2;s:39:"easy-google-fonts/easy-google-fonts.php";i:3;s:50:"google-analytics-for-wordpress/googleanalytics.php";i:4;s:19:"jetpack/jetpack.php";i:5;s:29:"pirate-forms/pirate-forms.php";i:6;s:43:"shortcodes-ultimate/shortcodes-ultimate.php";i:7;s:41:"sp-news-and-widget/sp-news-and-widget.php";i:8;s:27:"tawkto-live-chat/tawkto.php";i:9;s:43:"themeisle-companion/themeisle-companion.php";i:10;s:37:"tinymce-advanced/tinymce-advanced.php";i:11;s:24:"wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php";i:12;s:32:"wp-overlays/wp-overlays-lite.php";i:13;s:25:"cloudflare/cloudflare.php";}
```

any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should turn off SSL at your site and at cloudflare. See if that works.

Then set dns at cloudflare to bypass the cdn (grey cloud). Get ssl going on your site, and see if it loads under https.

If all that works, you can now turn on ssl at cloudflare (FULL, not Flexible) and switch dns back to using cloudflare (orange cloud).

Comment: I can't disable SSL and when I turn CloudFlare off, the website isn't opening it forces me the browser to https version.  I updated my question with the current open plugins

Comment: You have to make sure wordpress uses the non-https url versions for itself. Then try loading the site without SSL. Be sure to clear all of your caches first - including dns cache!

Answer (score 0):

Also,disable SSL and clean the cache, I'm sure that out there is a plugin for WP to help to propagate ssl url's, be sure you have it too, but what fixed my problem was disabling the rocket loader, you can find it in the speed option in cloudfare.

Comment: I can't disable SSL and when I turn CloudFlare off, the website isn't opening it forces me the browser to https version.  I updated my question with the current open plugins